Polygon envelope. Contour and total surface
I'm starting out using ArcGIS and I don't know how to get the perimeter of a polygon set.
The resulting layer has to be the total surface area of ​​the polygons that form it. could someone tell me how to do it?

I dont understand, you want to add columns with area and perimeter for each polygon/row? Why does your title say envelope? Are you asking how to do it in QGIS or ArcGIS?

Hello Bera,
First of all, thank you for your comment.
I want to do it in ArcGIS.
What I need to get is the envelope of all the polygons. This new area will have a total surface that will be the sum of the area of ​​all the polygons, but all the polygons will have become a single surface.
Sorry for my English, it is not my native language.

If you just need the area covered by the entire set of polygons, do a dissolve and recalculate your area field.  Or if you really need the length of the perimeter  recalculate that field.  If you have gaps in your set you could first fill them in by drawing a simple polygon or polygons over the gaps and overlapping your polygon set using the autocomplete polygon tool.

Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Your question is unclear and could do with some more detail.  However, I'm assuming that you want to get the area and perimeter of the minimal single convex polygon that covers all of your existing polygons.  This is often referred to as a 'convex hull'.
Use the 'Minimum Bounding Geometry' tool with the Group parameter set to 'All' and the Geometry Type parameter set to 'Convex Hull'.
This will create the minimal single polygon that covers all of your existing polygons, without any concave edges.
If you choose an output that is in a geodatabase, it will automatically include 'Shape_Area' and 'Shape_Length' fields, for the area and perimeter.  If your output is a Shapefile, then you can use the 'Add Geometry Attributes' tool to add and calculate area and perimeter.
Alternatively, if you want the minimal envelope, instead of a convex hull, the Minimum Bounding Geometry tool has other options for rectangle, circle, etc.
